# E: Unable to locate package wine-devel

Tags: wine

I want to install wine and my pc is giving me the response

```
E: Unable to locate package wine-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need wine repository.

> First of all, If you are running with 64-bit system enable 32-bit
>   architecture. Also, install the key which was used to sign packages of
>   wine.
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
>
> ###  Ubuntu 18.10 
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ cosmic main'
>
> ###  Ubuntu 18.04 
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
>
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
> ```

[Reference](https://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu/)